# How to hide the event title in Full calendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using full calendar, and i am having a problem making a simple reservation on a given day. the problem is that i dont know how to remove/hide the title in every event that is created within a day.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: im using the latest version of full calendar.

Comment: Have a look at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender

Answer (score 0):

I added a CSS to hide the event title using the `.fc-title` selector.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: ['dayGrid'],
    events: [
      {
        title: 'Event Title',
        start: '2019-06-13'
      }
    ]
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```css
.fc-title {
  visibility: hidden; /* hides event title */
}
```

```html
<div id='calendar'></div>


<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fullcalendar.io/releases/core/4.1.0/main.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fullcalendar.io/releases/daygrid/4.1.0/main.min.css'>
<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/releases/core/4.1.0/main.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/releases/daygrid/4.1.0/main.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't elaborate my question, i think it is " how can i hide the multiple titles of event in month view and only put a single title there, but still the title in TimeGridview is present"

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple titles"?

Comment: I mean when i have multiple events in a day, Example (I have an event from 9am -12pm) and from the day view, I can see the timeline of all the events present in that day, but it is also displayed in month view. I just wanted to display only "Open" or "Full".

Comment: @ChristianBaldeo There's no direct way to do that. The only way I can think of is that you would have to supply a separate set of events to be shown only in the month view. The way you'd make them only display in a certain view (which is not normally supported) would probably be to add a [custom property](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) to each event containing the name of the view they're destined for, and then filter them at the [eventRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender) stage, based on the current view and the property of the event.

Comment: @ChristianBaldeo P.S. It would help a lot if you clarified that exact requirement in your main question, by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56573750/edit)

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate your answer. i'll try doing it in different approach. Sorry for that, i'm just new to this forum

Comment: You can do that by adding dayRender and eventRender callback functions which overwrite default behavior. That way you can make your events or even the cells render in whatever way you like it. You can even do it differently per view. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayRender and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender